# Where is the syntax error Zapier Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.7, zapier

I am writing a Zap that appends leads in salesforce by checking if a phone number or email (on the lead record) exists in our MySQL database. If the number or email does exist in MySQL, it appends add'l info to the lead in Salesforce. I am at the point where I am defining the values in a python dictionary to pass to salesforce - I am taking the input dictionary (a combination of values from the salesforce webhook and the additional information gathered from MySQL) and narrowing it down to only the values I want to pass to salesforce. When i test the Python step, i get an error messages that just says 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax (, line 34)'. Line 34 looks like the other chunks of code so I am not sure what is unique about it. I've searched Stack Overflow and the internet for hours to no avail. Any input is appreciated.

I have searched the Python 3.7 manual and scoured the internet for clues to no avail.

Here is the input_data dict:
(link removed - contained PII)

```
    output = {
    'company' : '',
    'firstname':'',
    'lastname':'',
    'phone1':'',
    'phone2':'',
    'phone3':'',
    'email':'',
    'industry':''
}


if(('ENTER' in input_data['company'] or 'nullString' in input_data['company']) and input_data['company_sql'] != 'NA'):
    output['company'] = input_data['company_sql']
else:
    output['company'] = input_data['company']


if(('ENTER' in input_data['lastname'] or 'nullString' in input_data['lastname']) and input_data['lastname_sql'] != 'NA'):
    output['lastname'] = input_data['lastname_sql']
else:
    output['lastname'] = input_data['lastname']


if(('ENTER' in input_data['firstname'] or 'nullString' in input_data['firstname']) and input_data['firstname_sql'] != 'NA'):
    output['firstname'] = input_data['firstname_sql']
elif(('ENTER' in input_data['firstname'] or 'nullString' in input_data['firstname']) and input_data['firstname_sql'] = 'NA'):
    output['firstname'] = 'ENTER'
else:
    output['firstname'] = input_data['firstname']


if('nullString' in input_data['email'] and input_data['email_sql'] != 'NA'):
    output['email'] = input_data['email_sql']
elif('nullString' in input_data['email'] and input_data['email_sql'] == 'NA'):
    output['email'] = ''
else:
    output['email'] = input_data['email']


if('nullString' in input_data['phone1'] and input_data['phone1_sql'] != 'NA'):
    output['phone1'] = input_data['phone1_sql']
elif('nullString' in input_data['phone1'] and input_data['phone1_sql'] == 'NA'):
    output['phone1'] = ''
else:
    output['phone1'] = input_data['phone1']


if('nullString' in input_data['phone2'] and input_data['phone2_sql'] != 'NA'):
    output['phone2'] = input_data['phone2_sql']
elif('nullString' in input_data['phone2'] and input_data['phone2_sql'] == 'NA'):
    output['phone2'] = ''
else:
    output['phone2'] = input_data['phone2']


if('nullString' in input_data['phone3'] and input_data['phone3_sql'] != 'NA'):
    output['phone3'] = input_data['phone3_sql']
elif('nullString' in input_data['phone3'] and input_data['phone3_sql'] == 'NA'):
    output['phone3'] = ''
else:
    output['phone3'] = input_data['phone3']


if 'NA' in input_data['industry_sql']:
    output['industry'] = ''
else:
    output['industry'] = input_data['industry_sql']
```

I expected to get an output file with each value defined by the values I want to write back to salesforce (a mixture of values from the original webhook from salesforce, the values found in mysql, and blank values). I tried substituting strings in for the blank values but that didn't work either. I also contacted Zapier support but they told me to come here.

Comment: You should use double equals here: `input_data['firstname_sql'] = 'NA'`

Comment: @Selcuk you are amazing. I've been staring at this for too long! Thank you!

Comment: If you are using a text editor to write code, please don't. Use a proper IDE (such as PyCharm) which will highlight the actual syntax errors for you instead.

Comment: You have been using parentheses a lot but on a single one is necessary in your code.